# Yii2 Запись идентификатора пользователя в БД

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, kartik

Я начинающий разработчик на Yii2 и у меня возник следующий вопрос - с которым я не могу справиться своими силами. Мне нужно сделать на сайте просмотр и прикрепление документов в формате pdf doc docx к форме создания нового пользователя. Проблема - в том - что на сайте - в левой его части есть форма которая загружает аватар пользователя AJAX -  для нее я использовал виджет[image: введите сюда описание изображения] kartik file upload. Таким образом мне нужно без перезагрузки страницы загрузить документ(сделать возможность предпросмотра этого документа) и связать его с пользователем которые будет создаваться. Я планирую использовать тот же виджет kartik file upload и сделать таблицу где будут храниться пути к файлам загруженным через этот виджет - каким образом после загрузки файла и его отображения на странице можно будет записать в базу данных идентификатор пользователя, которому он принадлежит, если фотографии и сам документ отправляется Ajax - а вся форма - методом Post?

Comment: А вы как фото храните? Можно создать отдельную таблицу аля `users_atachments` и туда записывать user_id + путь к файлу, к примеру

Comment: Путь к фото я храню в таблице candidates, как отдельное поле - с этой задачей я справился - проблема в том - что идентификатор пользователя будет создан только после отправки всей формы методом Post - с прикрепленной к нему аватаркой и документом(который загружается Ajax)! Мне нужно как то его получить на этом этапе - и записать в БД - в новую таблицу files или users_attachments! Это я и не знаю как сделать, потому - что и картинка и файл записываются в БД перед отправки всей формы.

Comment: Ну, по сути вам id просто узнать же надо?.. `Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->execute();` создаётся запись и сразу после этого берётся id -> `$id = Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();` Или если вы через `save()` сохраняете -> `$user = new User(); $user->name = 'name'; if($user->save()){ $id = $user->id; //и тут можно сделать сохранение док-та }`

Comment: Спасибо  InDevX за развернутый ответ - я понял - что мне надо взять последний добавленный id - и сделать update - моей таблицы users_attachments - таким образом занеся в нее id пользователя!

Comment: зачем update? Вы проверяйте, если добавлен пользователь то тогда только создавайте запись в users_attachments, раньше не нужно добавлять

Comment: В том - и проблема - у меня - загрузка документа и соответственно запись о нем в users_attachments - должна происходить раньше чем создание пользователя - насколько я понимаю. я сначала прикрепляю файл к форме создания пользователя -  и только после этого создаю пользователя.

Comment: Нет. Вы готовите еду а потом покупаете продукты чтобы приготовить? Или всё-таки сперва продукты, потом готовка?.. Прикрепление док-та ничего никуда не отправляет, оно только "прикрепляет" файл к форме, так же, как и аватар. А вот сабмит уже должен сохранять и аватар и всё остальное

Comment: Да - вы правы - но все таки - kartik file input - позволяет мне сделать запись в БД - Ajax - то есть без отправки  всей формы методом POST. Ведь мне по сути нужно обновить только определенную область в форме - а не всю форму. Вот ссылка на сам виджет: http://demosbs3.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput. Или я где то очень сильно заблуждаюсь? Если я буду отправлять - всю форму - у меня - пропадет - все и аватар -и прикрепленный документ  - а я хочу чтобы пользователь мог прикрепить их динамически.

Comment: Тут ошибка в логике, ибо нельзя добавить что-то кому-то, кого не существует. Нельзя добавить аватар пользователю, которого нет. Этот плагин можно юзать для уже зарегистрированных пользователей при смене аватара. На самом то деле, не трудно и всю регистрацию сделать на ajax безо всяких плагинов

Comment: Да - мне говорили за этот вариант - переделать всю форму Ajax - без плагинов - но к сожалению я начинающий разработчик и мне с этой задачей не справиться.

Comment: Вы попробуйте, там ничего трудного нет, сами в этом убедитесь

Comment: Хорошо - спасибо Вам - за комментарии!!!